# C program to write a GUESS game with certain constraints. Problems occuring - error in code, logic of code, suggesstions

Tags: c, recursion, syntax-error, logic

**Question :**

Write a guessing game where the user has to guess a secret number. After every guess the program tells the user whether their number was too large or too small. At the end the number of tries needed should be printed. It counts only as one try if they input the same number multiple times consecutively.

**My code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int compare(int m) {
    int b;
    b=73-m; ///I chose my number as 73 here.

    if (b=0) printf("Congrats, you won.");
    else {
        if (-5 < b < 5) printf("Very Close\n"); ///always gives me this output two times.
        else {
            if (-15 < b < 15) printf("Close");
            else {
                printf("You are far");
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int arr[100],guess,count=0,i,m; ///I have 99 tries.
    arr[0]=0;
    for(i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++) {
        printf("Enter your guess\n");
        scanf("%d",&guess);
        if(guess==arr[i-1]) {
            arr[i]=guess;
            printf("Guess is same as the previous input.\n");
        } else {
            arr[i]=guess;
            compare(guess);
            if (m = compare(guess)) {
                count=count+1; /// can i create a separate function to keep the count?
                printf("%d is the number of tries.\n",count);
                break;
            } else {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is always giving me **the same output two times** i.e "Very close Very close". This is either faulty code (syntax) or wrong logic, I think. Also I **want to know a better algorithm/logic** with the code to solve this question (possibly shorter). Lastly *I am new to programming* with C as my first language.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warning, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `if (-15 < b < 15) `  a multiple value `if()` cannot be written this way in C.  Suggest:  `if( -15 < b && b < 15 )`  There are multiple occurrances of this incorrect syntax in the posted code.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understand: 1)  do not use single character variable names.  They are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) due to (probable) later editing of the code, do not omit optional braces '{' and '}'.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a #define statement or `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `compare(guess);
            if (m = compare(guess)) `  Why call `compare()` twice in a row?  Suggest removing the first statement

Comment: regarding: `for(i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++) `  there are only 100 entries in the `arr[]` array and in C, array offsets start at 0 so an offset of 100 is beyond the end of the array.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `-5 < b< 5` is equal to `(-5 < b) < 5`, which means you compare the boolean (`0` or `1`) result of `-5 < b` with `5`.

If you need to compare `b` to a range you need to do `-5 < b && b < 5`. I.e. compare `b` explicitly against both ends of the range.

Also, `b = 0` is ***assignment*** not comparison, you need to use `==` for comparison.